# Prevent OAuth client from modifying user's request

Tags: security, twitter, oauth

I use a web application developed by some company to manage my social information. This web application integrates various social sites (like twitter, facebook, google+) into one. Using this application I can send tweets, read emails, and create friend requests.

The web application uses OAuth 2.0 protocol to get access to my data in these social sites. After I login to this web application, I am redirected to twitter page, and then shown a page that says that the web application needs to be able to send tweets, etc, and ask for my approval. Once I approve, I can send tweets using this web application.

To send a tweet, I type the tweet, and then click a button in the web application. At the back, the web application sends a request to twitter using OAuth access token.

What I am worried here is that the web application may modify my tweet. Is there a way in OAuth 2.0 protocol to guarantee that the web application does not modify the tweet?

Answer (score 0):

I posted the question to OAuth Google Groups. Nat Sakimura kindly answered the question. You can see the answer at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/oauth/2OdlR40fZsI.